# How do I remove the last row in the printed list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question asked of me is to do the following

Print the 2-dimensional list mult_table by row and column. Hint: Use nested loops. Sample output for the given program:

```
1 | 2 | 3
2 | 4 | 6
3 | 6 | 9
```

So far I have this:

```
mult_table = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [3, 6, 9]
]

for row in mult_table:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell, end=' | ')
    print()
```

The output this gives me is:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 
2 | 4 | 6 | 
3 | 6 | 9 |
```

I need to know how I can remove the last column of `|` that is being printed.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Don't use `end` on the last column. Use `if` statement to check whether it is the last column.

Comment: You probably will want to keep track of the index you are currently iterating through for each cell. (Using `enumerate` or `range`). Then if it is the last index don't print out the `|`.

Comment: BTW, there is a one-liner for this, but you should learn the basics first, so nested loops are what you should do ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `str.join` method instead of always printing a pipe as an ending character:

```
for row in mult_table:
    print(' | '.join(map(str, row)))
```

Or you can use the `sep` parameter:

```
for row in mult_table:
    print(*row, sep=' | ')
```